# Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary

What is the difference between `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` in Java?

I don't see any difference in the output as all the three has `keySet` and `values`.

Also, what are `Hashtable`s?

```
Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("map", "HashMap");
m1.put("schildt", "java2");
m1.put("mathew", "Hyden");
m1.put("schildt", "java2s");
print(m1.keySet()); 
print(m1.values()); 

SortedMap<String, String> sm = new TreeMap<>();
sm.put("map", "TreeMap");
sm.put("schildt", "java2");
sm.put("mathew", "Hyden");
sm.put("schildt", "java2s");
print(sm.keySet()); 
print(sm.values());

LinkedHashMap<String, String> lm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
lm.put("map", "LinkedHashMap");
lm.put("schildt", "java2");
lm.put("mathew", "Hyden");
lm.put("schildt", "java2s");
print(lm.keySet()); 
print(lm.values());
```

Answer (score 1250, accepted):

All three classes implement the `Map` interface and offer mostly the same functionality. The most important difference is the order in which iteration through the entries will happen:

- `HashMap` makes absolutely no guarantees about the iteration order. It can (and will) even change completely when new elements are added.
- `TreeMap` will iterate according to the "natural ordering" of the keys according to their `compareTo()` method (or an externally supplied `Comparator`). Additionally, it implements the [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface, which contains methods that depend on this sort order.
- `LinkedHashMap` will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map

["Hashtable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) is the generic name for hash-based maps. In the context of the Java API,
`Hashtable` is an obsolete class from the days of Java 1.1 before the collections framework existed. It should not be used anymore, because its API is cluttered with obsolete methods that duplicate functionality, and its methods are synchronized (which can decrease performance and is generally useless). Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead of Hashtable.

Comment: What is then Map actually and whats the difference between Map,HashMap and Hashtables.

Comment: @theband: Map is an interface. HashMap and Hashtable both implement it; as I wrote, Hashtable is a legacy class.

Comment: @theband: Read the API doc, that's what it's for: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Comment: A notable difference between `Hashtable` and `HashMap` is that in a Hashtable, "neither the key nor the value can be null". This constraint does not exist on the latter.

Comment: it is possible to use Comparable or Comparator for implementing sorting mechanism in SortedMap (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108604/java-comparable-vs-comparator)

Comment: @AshkanN: Yes - in fact those are the standard ways to implement sorting. TreeMap has a constructor that takes a Comparator to use, and if none is provided, it expects all objects added to implement Comparable.

Comment: You can choose whether you want the LinkedHashMap iteration in insertion-order or access-order.

Answer (score 1834):

I prefer visual presentation:

| Property | HashMap | TreeMap | LinkedHashMap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Iteration Order | no guaranteed order, will remain constant over time | sorted according to the natural ordering | insertion-order |
| Get / put / remove / containsKey | O(1) | O(log(n)) | O(1) |
| Interfaces | Map | NavigableMap, Map, SortedMap | Map |
| Null values/keys | allowed | only values | allowed |
| Fail-fast behavior | Fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification | Fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification | Fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification |
| Implementation | buckets | Red-Black Tree | double-linked buckets |
| Is synchronized | implementation is not synchronized | implementation is not synchronized | implementation is not synchronized |

Comment: In addition to insertion-order, LinkedHashMap also supports access-order (when using the constructor with the boolean access-order param).

Comment: Double Linked Buckets? I think that adds unnecessary overhead of searching for the bucket for insertion/removal operations (because it has to search for the right bucket to put the object in). I always thought that LinkedHashMap implementations would be similar to that of a Map but with a little extra overhead of "entries list" (may be as a linked list) that's used for iteration purposes. Are you sure, shevchyk? If yes, can you explain or give me some online links that back your statement?

Comment: @SaiDubbaka LinkedHashMap has the double linked buckets BUT ALSO the bucket table HashMap has. It's not replacing it. This means that accessing buckets is done in the same way as in HashMap, as the linked list is there for iteration in insertion order (or access order) only.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning, that O(1) is the best case scenario (which we wouldn't usually call O, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on))

Comment: It's also worth noting that O(1) isn't always better than O(log n); if you have a very long key, something based on BSTs might be much faster than something that has to perform an O(n) hash on the whole key before being able to do anything.

Comment: love this visual presentation. See my analogous answer on Sets here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43364019/3886961 based on your work

Comment: It is not strictly true that a `TreeMap` disallows null keys.  If the `TreeMap` is using a `Comparator` that allows nulls, then the `TreeMap` can contain `null` keys.  For example, the following is a `TreeMap` with "A" mapped to `null`: `new TreeMap<>(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())).put(null, "A");`

Answer (score 68):

All three represent mapping from unique keys to values, and therefore implement the [Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.

1. HashMap is a map based on [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the keys. It supports O(1) get/put operations. Keys must have [consistent implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for this to work.
2. LinkedHashMap is very similar to HashMap, but it adds awareness to the order at which items are added (or accessed), so the iteration order is the same as insertion order (or access order, depending on construction parameters).
3. TreeMap is a tree based mapping. Its put/get operations take O(log n) time. It requires items to have some comparison mechanism, either with Comparable or Comparator. The iteration order is determined by this mechanism.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the only difference between LinkedHashMap and TreeMap is performance, given that the order of insertion is the same as the natural order?

Comment: @MosheShaham As he said in # 2: `LinkedHashMap` will iterate in the insertion order, not the natural order. So if you add `(2,5,3)` to a `LinkedHashMap` and do a for each over it, it will return `2,5,3`. If it were `2,5,3` to a `TreeMap` it will return `2,3,5`.

Comment: Tree map also has a lot of other nice tricks. Like head and tail maps.

Comment: private TreeMap<String ,Integer> mySection2 = new TreeMap<>();                      mySection2.put("abc1", 2); mySection2.put("abc2",5); mySection2.put("abc3",3);                                                                                   for(Integer x : mySection2.values()) {
            Log.e("LOG","TreeMap===="+x);
        }                                                                                   This is giving me the same order as items were inserted ?please suggest how is it different from LinkedHashMaps ?

Comment: @B.shruti: This is because your insertion order matches the lexicographic order of your keys ("abc1", "abc2", "abc3"). If you insert in a different order, your code will still iterate according to the lexicographic ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, basically what i get as a difference between tree and linked hash map is linked hasmap would iterate the values in order they were inseted , but tree Map would iterate the values according to natural ordering /lexicograhic/sorted odering of "keys" not values.

Answer (score 54):

See where each class is in the class hierarchy in the following diagram ([bigger one](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LUCDWSG5qXE/Uy_ee5bIR5I/AAAAAAAAAZA/oY1hR_1fcwk/s1600/Java+collection+cheat+sheet.PNG)). TreeMap implements `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap` while `HashMap` doesn't.

`HashTable` is obsolete and the corresponding `ConcurrentHashMap` class should be used.
[image]

Comment: this is amazing answer with this diagram

Answer (score 42):

#### HashMap

- It has pair values(keys,values)
- NO duplication key values
- unordered unsorted
- it allows one null key and more than one null values

#### HashTable

- same as hash map
- it does not allows null keys and null values

#### LinkedHashMap

- It is ordered version of map implementation
- Based on linked list and hashing data structures

#### TreeMap

- Ordered and sortered version
- based on hashing data structures

Comment: Also HashTable is synchronized. Anyways,, I like your answer, clean and clear.

Answer (score 38):

Just some more input from my own experience with maps, on when I would use each one:

- HashMap - Most useful when looking for a best-performance (fast) implementation.
- TreeMap (SortedMap interface) - Most useful when I'm concerned with being able to sort or iterate over the keys in a particular order that I define.
- LinkedHashMap - Combines advantages of guaranteed ordering from TreeMap without the increased cost of maintaining the TreeMap.  (It is almost as fast as the HashMap).  In particular, the LinkedHashMap also provides a great starting point for creating a Cache object by overriding the [`removeEldestEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) method.  This lets you create a Cache object that can expire data using some criteria that you define.

Comment: To be precise, TreeMap doesn't keep the elements in order.  It keeps the keys in order.

Answer (score 24):

All three classes `HashMap`, `TreeMap` and `LinkedHashMap` implements `java.util.Map` interface, and represents mapping from unique key to values.

**[HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap)**

1. A `HashMap` contains values based on the key.
2. It contains only    unique elements.
3. It may have one null key and multiple null values.
4. It maintains ***no order***.

   `public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable`

**[LinkedHashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#LinkedHashMap)**

1. A `LinkedHashMap` contains values based on the key.
2. It contains only unique elements.
3. It may have one null key and multiple null values.
4. It is same as HashMap instead maintains ***insertion order***. *//See class deceleration below*

   `public class LinkedHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>`

**[TreeMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap)**

1. A `TreeMap` contains values based on the key. It implements the NavigableMap interface and extends AbstractMap class.
2. It contains only unique elements.
3. It cannot have null key but can have multiple null values.
4. It is same as `HashMap` instead maintains ***ascending order***(Sorted using the natural order of its key.).

   `public class TreeMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable`

**[Hashtable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable)**

1. A Hashtable is an array of list. Each list is known as a bucket. The position of bucket is identified by calling the hashcode() method. A Hashtable contains values based on the key.
2. It contains only unique elements.
3. It may have not have any null key or value.
4. It is ***synchronized***.
5. It is a legacy class.

   `public class Hashtable<K,V> extends Dictionary<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable`

[image]

Ref: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/08/difference-between-HashMap-vs-TreeMap-vs-LinkedHashMap-Java.html

Comment: Big-O notation of HashMap should not be O(1). That's the *best* case, and hashtables have O(n) as their worst case scenario. This is supported by your link.

Comment: see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1/1055337#1055337

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit I will also suggest to go for actual code here - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap

Comment: That STILL says that it's O(n) in the worst case. It's a mathematical concept, and you don't get to say that it's O(1), unless it's actually O(1). You're also assuming some really good hashing functions here. I mean, we could use something like class TerribleHashKey { @Override hashCode() { return 4; /* Determined by fair dice throw */ }} and use that as a key for other fun stuff. Having a high probability of O(1) and having O(1) is not the same. People come here for help with their homework. Let's not ruin their grades.. ;)

Comment: And it would be worth noticing that in Java 8 you have worst case of O(log(n)) if you have more than 8 buckets, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java for details about this.

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit above complexity is for well optimized hash function in Java library. And of course we can assume that a novice programmer can always write something like `public int hashCode() { return 4; }` for **O(N)**

Comment: also read @Daniel James ans, He explained well -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1/1055277#1055277

Comment: Daniel James is talking about little-o notation, not big-O notation. It's hence not very relevant. Furthermore, when you admit that a programmer can casually break the speed of the hashing function, degrading it to O(n) or O(log (n)) depending on the version of Java, you cannot then turn around and claim O(1). If you were to say "average case" I would however, have *no* argument with what you're saying. :-)

Answer (score 13):

> HashMap makes absolutely not guarantees about the iteration order. It
>   can (and will) even change completely when new elements are added.
>   TreeMap will iterate according to the "natural ordering" of the keys
>   according to their compareTo() method (or an externally supplied
>   Comparator). Additionally, it implements the SortedMap interface,
>   which contains methods that depend on this sort order. LinkedHashMap
>   will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map

Look at how performance varying..
[image]

Tree map which is an implementation of Sorted map. The complexity of the put, get and containsKey operation is O(log n) due to the Natural ordering

Comment: Thank you, LinkedHashMap's "O(1) expense for maintaining the order" makes sense but do you have a reference to a more detailed explaination?

Answer (score 9):

@Amit: `SortedMap` is an interface whereas `TreeMap` is a class which implements the `SortedMap` interface. That means if follows the protocol which `SortedMap` asks its implementers to do.
A tree unless implemented as search tree, can't give you ordered data because tree can be any kind of tree. So to make TreeMap work like Sorted order, it implements SortedMap ( e.g, Binary Search Tree - BST, balanced BST like AVL and R-B Tree , even Ternary Search Tree - mostly used for iterative searches in ordered way ).

```
public class TreeMap<K,V>
extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements SortedMap<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

In NUT-SHELL
`HashMap` : gives data in O(1) , no ordering

`TreeMap` : gives data in O(log N), base 2. with ordered keys

`LinkedHashMap` : is Hash table with linked list (think of indexed-SkipList) capability to store data in the way it gets inserted in the tree. Best suited to implement LRU ( least recently used ).

Answer (score 7):

Hash map doesn't  preserves the insertion order.
Example.  Hashmap
If you are inserting keys as

```
1  3
5  9
4   6
7   15
3   10
```

It can store it as

```
4  6
5  9
3  10
1  3
7  15
```

Linked Hashmap  preserves the insertion order.

Example.
If you are inserting keys

```
1  3
5  9
4   6
7   15
3   10
```

It will store it as

```
1  3
5  9
4   6
7   15
3   10
```

same as we insert.

Tree map stores the vales in Increasing Order Of Keys. 
Example.
If you are inserting keys

```
1  3
5  9
4   6
7   15
3   10
```

It will store it as

```
1  3
3  10
4   6
5   9
7   15
```

Answer (score 7):

- HashMap:

  - Order not maintains
  - Faster than LinkedHashMap
  - Used for store heap of objects
- LinkedHashMap:

  - LinkedHashMap insertion order will be maintained
  - Slower than HashMap and faster than TreeMap
  - If you want to maintain an insertion order use this.
- TreeMap:

  - TreeMap is a tree-based mapping
  - TreeMap will follow the natural ordering of key
  - Slower than HashMap and LinkedHashMap
  - Use TreeMap when you need to maintain natural(default) ordering

Answer (score 6):

Following are major difference between HashMap and TreeMap

1. HashMap does not maintain any order. In other words , HashMap does not provide any guarantee that the element inserted first will be printed first, where as Just like TreeSet , TreeMap  elements are also sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements
2. Internal HashMap implementation use Hashing and TreeMap internally uses Red-Black tree implementation.
3. HashMap can store one null key and many  null values.TreeMap can not contain null keys but may contain many null values.
4. HashMap  take constant time performance for the basic operations like get and put i.e O(1).According to Oracle docs , TreeMap provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the get and put method.
5. HashMap is much faster than TreeMap, as performance time of HashMap is constant against the log time TreeMap for most operations.
6. HashMap uses equals() method in comparison while TreeMap uses compareTo() method for maintaining ordering.
7. HashMap implements Map interface while TreeMap implements NavigableMap interface.

Answer (score 4):

The most important among all the three is how they save the order of the entries.

`HashMap` - Does not save the order of the entries.
eg.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("First",1);// First ---> 1 is put first in the map
        hashMap.put("Second",2);//Second ---> 2 is put second in the map
        hashMap.put("Third",3); // Third--->3 is put third in the map
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"--->"+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

[image: Output for HashMap]

`LinkedHashMap` : It save the order in which entries were made. eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        linkedHashMap.put("First",1);// First ---> 1 is put first in the map
        linkedHashMap.put("Second",2);//Second ---> 2 is put second in the map
        linkedHashMap.put("Third",3); // Third--->3 is put third in the map
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : linkedHashMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"--->"+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

[image: Output of LinkedHashMap]

`TreeMap` : It saves the entries in ascending order of the keys. eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TreeMap<String,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        treeMap.put("A",1);// A---> 1 is put first in the map
        treeMap.put("C",2);//C---> 2 is put second in the map
        treeMap.put("B",3); //B--->3 is put third in the map
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"--->"+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

[image: Output of TreeMap]

Comment: I like your examples

Answer (score 4):

While there are plenty of excellent Answers here, I'd like to present my own table describing the various `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11.

We can see these differences listed on the table graphic:

- [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is the **general-purpose** [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) commonly used when you have no special needs.
- [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) extends `HashMap`, adding this behavior: Maintains an order, the **order in which the entries were originally added**. Altering the value for key-value entry does not alter its place in the order.
- [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) too maintains an order, but uses either (a) the **“natural” order**, meaning the value of the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method on the key objects defined on the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, or (b) invokes **a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation** you provide.

  - `TreeMap` implements both the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface, and its successor, the [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface.
- [NULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer)s: `TreeMap` does ***not* allow a NULL as the key**, while `HashMap` & `LinkedHashMap` do.

  - All three allow NULL as the value.
- [`HashTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) is **[legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), from Java 1**. Supplanted by the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class. Quoting the Javadoc: `ConcurrentHashMap` obeys the same functional specification as `Hashtable`, and includes versions of methods corresponding to each method of `Hashtable`.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Answer (score 3):

These are different implementations of the same interface. Each implementation has some advantages and some disadvantages (fast insert, slow search) or vice versa.

For details look at the javadoc of [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), [HashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: What are Hashtables actually and what makes it differ from a Map.

Answer (score 2):

All offer a key->value map and a way to iterate through the keys. The most important distinction between
these classes are the time guarantees and the ordering of the keys.

1. HashMap offers 0(1) lookup and insertion. If you iterate through the keys, though, the ordering of the
   keys is essentially arbitrary. It is implemented by an array of linked lists.
2. TreeMap offers O(log N) lookup and insertion. Keys are ordered, so if you need to iterate through
   the keys in sorted order, you can. This means that keys must implement the Comparable interface.TreeMap is implemented by a Red-Black Tree.
3. LinkedHashMap offers 0(1) lookup and insertion. Keys are ordered by their insertion order. It is
   implemented by doubly-linked buckets.

Imagine you passed an empty TreeMap, HashMap, and LinkedHashMap into the following function:

```
void insertAndPrint(AbstractMap<Integer, String> map) {
  int[] array= {1, -1, 0};
  for (int x : array) {
    map.put(x, Integer.toString(x));
  }
  for (int k: map.keySet()) {
   System.out.print(k + ", ");
  }
}
```

The output for each will look like the results below.

For HashMap, the output was, in my own tests, { 0, 1, -1}, but it could be any ordering. There is no guarantee on the
ordering.
Treemap,the output was,{ -1, 0, 1}
LinkedList,the output was,{ 1, -1, 0}

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap**
can contain one null key.

HashMap maintains no order.

**TreeMap**

TreeMap can not contain any null key.

TreeMap maintains ascending order.

**LinkedHashMap**

LinkedHashMap can be used to maintain insertion order, on which keys are inserted into Map or it can also be used to maintain an access order, on which keys are accessed.

**Examples**::

1) HashMap map = new HashMap();

```
    map.put(null, "Kamran");
    map.put(2, "Ali");
    map.put(5, "From");
    map.put(4, "Dir");`enter code here`
    map.put(3, "Lower");
    for (Map.Entry m : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + "  " + m.getValue());
    }
```

2) TreeMap map = new TreeMap();

```
    map.put(1, "Kamran");
    map.put(2, "Ali");
    map.put(5, "From");
    map.put(4, "Dir");
    map.put(3, "Lower");
    for (Map.Entry m : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + "  " + m.getValue());
    }
```

3) LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap();

```
    map.put(1, "Kamran");
    map.put(2, "Ali");
    map.put(5, "From");
    map.put(4, "Dir");
    map.put(3, "Lower");
    for (Map.Entry m : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + "  " + m.getValue());
    }
```