# Performance of TreeMap, HashMap and LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

In TreeMap - Elements are sorted
In HashMap - Elements are not sorted

So, if I consider `get`, `put` and `remove` methods which map should I use for performance?

Comment: See the Javadoc. `HashMap` is specified to be O(1): 'constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets'. `TreeMap` is specified to 'guaranteed log(n) time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations.

Comment: Without knowing your criteria for assessing which option would be better, answering this question is impossible. Clearly, if you need a sorted collection only `TreeMap` will do. But you already know that.

Comment: Pretty detailed here: [difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)

Comment: The accepted answer says `HashMap` is faster. But the Javadocs for `LinkedHashMap` (Java 8) says that it iterates considerably faster than `HashMap`. So YMMV, depending on your specific criteria. Definitely don't use `TreeMap` unless you need _sorting_, and use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `HashMap` unless you have some need for ordering.  `HashMap` is faster.

That said, you can make it easy to switch by using the generic interface as your declaration:

```
 Map<String,String> M = new HashMap<String,String>();
 ...use M lots of places...
```

Then all you have to do is switch one place and your code uses the new map type.

### Edit:

A simple timing test:

```
import java.util.*;
class TimingTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,String> M = new HashMap<String,String>();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      M.put(Integer.toString(i), "foo");
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);
  }
}
```

Comment: @keith-Can you please tell me, How is hashmap faster than treemap??
Treemap access values on keys sequentially. Can you please tell me how hashmap works??

Comment: The answer is longer than will fit in this comment.  Take a data structures class, or read up on hash tables and red-black trees on Wikipedia.  Hash tables are `O(1)` amortized work per operation, assuming a good hash function.  Red-black trees are `O(lg n)` work per operation.

Comment: I have tried examples for treemap and hashmap...I entered 100000 entry in map and access them.. I counted time. but result for my programs is
treemap-187
hashmap 206
means hashmap requires more time...Got confused, please explain me what is your opinion on this?

Comment: I don't get the same result.  Putting 100000 entries into a map takes about 60 msec for a `HashMap` and 90 msec for a `TreeMap`.  I'll post my code.

Comment: ok, Have you tried with both sequential and non sequential numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how fast the hash and comparison functions are on the keys in your map. It depends on whether you're more interested in average case performance or worst-case performance. It depends on whether you have a good hash function applied to your map's keys; hash values should be well distributed across the hash function's domain (yes, it can depend on your data).

In general (when you can't be bothered to test), a hash map is often a good answer, but it's also unlikely to make a big difference if you don't have a thousands of entries (for small sizes, a "vec map" can also work well).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your intentions, in terms of iteration:

- The HashMap makes no guarentee of such, wich means its random;
- The TreeMap uses natural order or a Comparator if specified;
- The LinkedHashMap is iterated according to insertion order.

Futhermore, for TimeComplexity for put/get/remove/containsKey:

- HashSet - O(1);
- TreeMap - O(log(n)) or O(1); -- see references!
- LinkedHashSet - O(1).

Geekforgeeks:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-treemap-hashmap-linkedhashmap-java/

StackOverflow:

- [Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)

Comment: All your references suggest O(log n) for TreeMap. Where does O(1) come from?