# what's the difference between HashSet and LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, hashset, linkedhashset

I saw that `LinkedHashSet` extends `HashSet` and I know it preserves order.
However, from checking the code in the JDK it seems that `LinkedHashSet` contains only constuctor and no implementation, so I guess all the logic happens in `HashSet`?
If that is correct, why is it designed like that? it seems very confusing.

*EDIT:* there was an unfortunate mistake in the question. I wrote `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet`. I fixed the question answer it if possible.
Also, I was interested why Java designers chose to implement it like that.

Comment: Where did you see that it contains only a Constructor? There are a bunch of methods in that class, some overriding the ones of HashMap. See here for example: http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.htm

Comment: Please recheck the [code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.html)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java

Comment: I edited the question, I am looking for new answers regarding `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `LinkedHashMap` calls its super constructor. One thing it does is to override the `init()` method, which is called by the super constructor.

The `LinkedHashMap` is an `HashMap` with a doubly-linked list implementation added.

Comment: I edited the question, I am looking for new answers regarding `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet`

Answer (score 0):

As you said the difference between the two data structures is that the `LinkedHashMap` is an `HashMap` that preserve the insertion order of pairs.

So the Linked one is intended to used as an `HashMap` via standard methods of the `HashMap` and the only method added is [removeEldestEntry()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29), useful if you want to deal with the "list" part of the data structure.

Comment: I edited the question, I am looking for new answers regarding `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet`