# Map Value Retrieval

Tags: java, select, collections, dictionary

I am storting the values of SELECT QUERY in a map , with combined month and year (Mon YY) as key. 
I used order by date in my query. Its working fine, but when i display the value of a map, its in random order.

Is there any way to get the first inserted element first ( like queue)?

```
  Inserting element
       Dec 2011     REC     332     12      
       Dec 2011     WER     12      12      
       Dec 2012     QA      212     12 

  Displaying value   
            Inner Key :Dec 2012
            QA
            212
            12
            Inner Key :Dec 2011
            REC
            332
            12
            WER
            12
            12
```

I need the values in ascending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a LinkedHashMap, which preserves insertion order.

Comment: Thanks...
This thread helps me to know about LinkedHashMap


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java

Comment: The javadoc would have helped you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: No, a TreeMap won't help, unless the key happens to be Comparable and to have a natural order that corresponds to how the data are already sorted.