# Alphabetize a HashMap of Characters

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a program that takes the number of instances of a character in a string and then puts them into a HashMap. I have it working, but how do I alphabetize the HashMap. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
public class CharacterCount
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      {
      String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in any text.");
      String str = s.replaceAll("[., ]", "");
      String[] splitted = str.split("");
      HashMap hm = new HashMap();

      for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
         if (!hm.containsKey(splitted[i])) {
            hm.put(splitted[i], 1);
         } else {
            hm.put(splitted[i], (Integer) hm.get(splitted[i]) + 1);
            }
      }
      for (Object word : hm.keySet()) {
         if (word.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Spaces: " + (Integer) hm.get(word));
            }
         else {
            System.out.println(word + ": " + (Integer) hm.get(word));
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What do I need to add to make it alphabetize/reorganize the HashMap?

Comment: You can't alphabetize a HashMap.  You *can* extract the entries of a HashMap into an array and sort the array, but a HashMap by definition is unordered.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/2889777/509840. If you declare it a SortedMap, it will be alphabetized by key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `HashMap` is, by default, unsorted. This because its implementation can't rely on order of elements.

If you need a sorted map then you will have to look into a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which supplies the same interface as a `HashMap` but it's inherently sorted on keys according to their natural ordering (or a custom `Comparator`). Mind that a `TreeMap` doesn't allow ordering on values, so if you need to sort your data by value then you will have to build your own sorted collection.

This is usually done by taking the `Map.Entry<K,V> entrySet()` and then build a new `SortedSet` by following your ordering rules.

Answer (score 0):

Most maps, including HashMap, make no promises about order of contents. Consider SortedMap, or maintaining both a hash map and a sorted list in parallel.

[Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java)