# Which Map to use in case of million records in Java

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have many records in to fetch and it could be in millions, I want to use hashmap, but I am not sure if that is ok or what would be the memory implications.

Please suggest

Thanks
VIvek

Comment: What are the class types of the keys and values you want to store in your map?

Comment: It is very unlikely you're going to have enough memory to store millions of anything in memory regardless of data structure used.

Comment: I think a[n external] database is going to work better for you.

Comment: it was more related to which collection would you use list, set, map and specifically which one of out of those in case of number of elements are huge

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange.  A good place to start would be taking a look at this question:

[Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap, and SortedMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java)

`HashMap` is generally discouraged if you need to grab items in a specific order.

If you need to store 1,000,000+ records, you may want to look into an external database to store the information, as it will be memory consuming to hold all of the records.

Comment: thanks Mike, I was asked this question in an interview, so I was not sure if database would the perfect answer for this

Comment: What if we don't have any DB to store this much value?can we use hash table and BST in that scenario?