# Appropriate collection class in Java for duplicate key, value pairs

Tags: java, collections

Which collection class should i use for the following data

```
(key1, value1)
(key1, value2)
(key2, value3)
(key3, value3)
```

keys and values are not distinct

Comment: take a look this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can either roll your own implementation of a:

```
Map<Key, List<Value>>
```

or use the [Multimap from Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap), in their documentation they explain it as:

> There are two ways to think of a Multimap conceptually: as a collection of mappings from single keys to single values:
>
> a -> 1 a -> 2 a -> 4 b -> 3 c -> 5
>
> or as a mapping from unique keys to collections of values:
>
> a -> [1, 2, 4] b -> 3 c -> 5

The following [blog post](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.ch/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html) explains some of the advantages of using the Guava collection.

There is also the [MultiValueMap from the Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html) that solves the same problem should you have a preference when it comes to external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for this use case is the `MultiValueMap` of Apache Commons Collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<List<String>,List<String>> map = new HashMap<List<String>,List<String>>();
List keys = new ArrayList();
keys.add("one");keys.add("one");keys.add("two");keys.add("three");
List values = new ArrayList();
values.add("First");values.add("First12");values.add("second");values.add("second");
map.put(keys, values);
System.out.println(map.keySet().toString());
System.out.println(map.values().toString());
System.out.println("map:"+map.toString());
```

Comment: Map<List<String>,List<String>> map = new HashMap<List<String>,List<String>>();