# ArrayList to HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to get values from an `ArrayList` that is sorted and want to store it in a `HashMap`,  where the values of the `ArrayList` become keys of the `HashMap`. Will the order of the values in the `HashMap` still be the same as that of `ArrayList`?

Comment: You can use a LinkedHashMap or a TreeMap depending on your use case

Comment: TreeMap is the one. Thanks

Comment: A HashMap is not guaranteed to hold the sort order. If you want to maintain the order in which they were inserted into the arraylist. I would recommend LinkedHashMap over TreeMap.
Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2889800/919858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order the mappings are stored or iterated, so simply running through the ArrayList and putting them into the HashMap as keys will very likely result in unordered iterations.

As others have pointed out, LinkedHashMap does preserve *insertion order* for iterations. An additional run of insertions will result in unordered iterations again, though. Both HashMap and LinkedHashMap support constant time lookup - LinkedHashMap pays for its extra feature in space (by maintaining pointers between the keys).

As others have also pointed out, TreeMap preserves order after updates, so this might be a better option for you, or not. Of course, if the ArrayList is sorted with a specific Comparator, you *must* feed that same Comparator to the TreeMap on construction for the sorting to be the same. Note that TreeMap does not have constant time lookup, due to being implemented as a Red-Black search tree.

Answer (score 2):

No. Use a TreeMap instead. This will preserve the order of insertion.

Comment: I was not aware of TreeMap data structure. Now I just read the documentation for it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that TreeMap only preserves order of insertion *if the order of insertion is sorted order*. It is in this case, but it's not an insignificant detail.

Comment: @AndreasTroelsen He explicitly said that the ArrayList was sorted.

Comment: @jhn Read my comment again. I acknowledge this specific use case. The TreeMap will preserve the order of insertion in this specific case, but as I pointed out in my answer, the TreeMap may add unnecessary complexity, and it *requires* a Comparator identical to the one used to sort the ArrayList (if it wasn't sorted due to the natural ordering). My comment was directed at the lack of possibly significant information, not at correctness.

Answer (score 0):

As your ArrayList has been ordered, no need to use a TreeMap because this will compare to order again and it's not necessary. You should use a LinkedHashMap that will keep the exact order of your ArrayList when you put your value in.

Answer (score -1):

Check This: **Insert Values of ArrayList into HashMap**

```
HashMap<String, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<String, Item>();

for (Item item : itemList) 
{
   itemMap.put(item.getitemCode(), item);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Also, OP specifically said *values of the ArrayList become keys of the HashMap*, but with this code, the values of the list become values of the map.