# Disadvantages of a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Are there any disadvantages of using a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap? Most posts seem to discuss the advantages of LinkedHashMaps (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java) or the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)), but I can't find any reason HashMaps are better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and SortedMap in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java)

Comment: Disadvantage is pretty much listed in the linked question - performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the docs say, `This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries.`. This has the benefit of allowing predictable iteration order, but the disadvantages are increased memory usage and probably higher insertion cost - nothing comes for free, the additional structure (linked list) uses some memory and requires extra CPU cost in order to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. `LinkedHashMap` differs from `HashMap` in that the order of elements is maintained.

So in order to maintain order, `LinkedHashMap` needs the expense of maintaining a linked list. Whereas a `HashMap` has no such overhead leading to a better performance than a `LinkedHashMap`.

Note that `LinkedHashMap` implements a normal hashtable, but with the added benefit of the keys of the hashtable being stored as a doubly-linked list.