# Using arrays to hold indices for other arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexing, iteration

I'm working on a program that requires a lot of indices for various arrays. I thought, that one of the methods for doing so would be to have an array that holds all of the indices. For example:

```
int[] indices = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
```

The result being "a" would be outputted once, "b" twice, etc.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Please explain the actual problem. Not only is this a case where something like a map will do what you described, it isn't indexing.

Comment: I would use Arrays only when you don't have other solutions (or when an Array is appropriate), what about a Map?

Comment: Well, the indexing is the end result, and this is just the process to get to that point. I believe I explained the scenario thoroughly; is there any thing that's abstruse? Basically it's just using the `indexes` array as a determinant for manipulating the `chars` array.

Comment: Java is an object-oriented language. Drop the C-style approach, and store an array of some CharCounter object that has both a char and int field.

Comment: What you are looking for is a dictionary datastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better Data Structure for your goal is  **Map** interface

> A **Map** is an object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain
>   duplicate keys: Each key can map to at most one value.

**Map Interface has various implementions**:

> 1. **HashMap** : The HashMap class uses a hashtable to implement the Map interface. This allows the execution time of basic operations, such as get( ) and put( ), to remain constant even for large sets.
> 2. **TreeMap**: The TreeMap class implements the Map interface by using a tree. A TreeMap provides an efficient means of storing key/value pairs in **sorted order**, and allows rapid retrieval.
> 3. **LinkedHashMap**:This class extends HashMap and maintains a linked list of the entries in the map, in the order in which they were inserted.
>      This allows insertion-order iteration over the map. That is, when iterating a LinkedHashMap, the elements will be returned in the order in which they were inserted.

**visual presentation**:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║   Property   ║       HashMap       ║      TreeMap      ║     LinkedHashMap    ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║              ║  no guarantee order ║ sorted according  ║                      ║
║   Order      ║ will remain constant║ to the natural    ║    insertion-order   ║
║              ║      over time      ║    ordering       ║                      ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║  Get/put     ║                     ║                   ║                      ║
║   remove     ║         O(1)        ║      O(log(n))    ║         O(1)         ║
║ containsKey  ║                     ║                   ║                      ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║              ║                     ║   NavigableMap    ║                      ║
║  Interfaces  ║         Map         ║       Map         ║         Map          ║
║              ║                     ║    SortedMap      ║                      ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║              ║                     ║                   ║                      ║
║     Null     ║       allowed       ║    only values    ║       allowed        ║
║ values/keys  ║                     ║                   ║                      ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════════════════╣
║              ║   Fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed       ║
║   Fail-fast  ║ impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of      ║
║   behavior   ║           unsynchronized concurrent modification               ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════════════════╣
║              ║                     ║                   ║                      ║
║Implementation║      buckets        ║   Red-Black Tree  ║    double-linked     ║
║              ║                     ║                   ║       buckets        ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════════════════╣
║      Is      ║                                                                ║
║ synchronized ║              implementation is not synchronized                ║
╚══════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

[Read about HashMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm)

[Read about TreeMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_treemap_class.htm)

[Read about LinkedHashMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedhashmap_class.htm)

[source for visual presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)

Comment: Basically what I was testing the most were a bunch of for loops that would preform the logic to accomplish this. The main reason why I don't want to go w/ a map is because I don't want to say "mymap.add( ... )" over and over again, or have a for loop do it for me that uses data from the arrays I've already set up and put said data in the map.

Comment: @T145 adding info to map uses put function. is there any reason that you don't want to use map?

Comment: Well, that's just "mymap.put( ... )"; the reasons still stand.

Comment: would you like to share your reason ?

Comment: Yes; I feel as though it would be great to use arrays and use maybe 10 lines for the logic rather than using way more than that just to supply inputs. If there were a way to translate my arrays into a map efficiently, then that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a lot of my answers use `HashMap` these days. I feel like its use is underestimated, specifically because it is so versatile at handling associated data.

```
HashMap<Char, Integer> foo = new HashMap<Char, Integer>();
foo.add('a', 1);
foo.add('b', 2);
foo.add('c', 3);
foo.add('d', 4);
foo.add('e', 5);

for(Entry<Char, Integer> e : foo.getEntrySet()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < e.getValue(); i++) {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

This, of course, assumes you don't have a preference for order. If you do, then instead you should use an `ArrayList` and an Object that stores a character and an Integer.

Creating multiple arrays that depend on each other is relatively unsafe, so you might as well create an Object that handles everything for you.

Comment: Do you really need *exactly* `HashMap` here? If not, please declare it as `Map`. And I think, that today it would be correct to use diamond syntax instead instead of repeating yourself with `<Char, Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe you do want to iterate your list in order, a Map is not suitable here. The better approach is to realize that you're in an object-oriented language; create an object to model your data:

```
class CharCounter {
  private final char toPrint;
  private final int times;
  public CharCounter(final char toPrint, final int times) {
    this.toPrint = toPrint;
    this.times = times;
  }
}

CharCounter[] arr = new CharCounter[]{ new CharCounter('a', 1), new CharCounter('b', 2), ...};
```

Comment: Not necessarily. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html