# Does a collection which is retrieved from map.values() method preserve insertion order?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, linkedhashmap, insertion-order

I have an instance of `LinkedHashMap`. `LinkedHashMap` preserves the insertion order. I need to get the values of this map and I need them to be in the same order. So if I call `values()` method on this `LinkedHashMap`, 
the `Collection` that I retrieve from `values()` method will guarantee the insertion order?

Comment: I think yes. You could verify it quickly.

Comment: The answer is yes as can be seen here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2889800/3584765

Comment: Note that demonstrating that a particular implementation preserves order does *not* answer this question. It is really a question about the API definition.

Comment: @Duncan I overread that my fault -> no exact duplicate

Comment: @KPJ If the map is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress(except through the iterator's own remove operation),the results of the iteration are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the source code of *LinkedHashMap* resides an inner class *LinkedValues* which remains the order. An object of this class is returned by *values()*.