# HashMap messes up the order of its own elements

Tags: java, hashmap, put, element

Simple as the title, I searched it up already, and I didn't find anything about this issue, I'm pretty sure I just misunderstood how a HashMap works with its own elements.
Super-simplest code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("first key", 1);
    map.put("second key", 2);
    map.put("third key", 3);

    System.out.println(map.toString());
```

What does the println() method show?
It shows this:

```
{third key=3, first key=1, second key=2}
```

I tough the HashMap stored elements as the programmer put them in.
Even a sorting would sort would place these elements as I put them in origin.
I tried changing the words and similar things happen(only the positions changed, but they were "wrong" anyway). :/
Do you know why?

Thanks in advance :/

EDIT:  Rohit Jain is actually the first that answered me as comment, and you guys told me about LinkedHashMap, so you helped me to solve, thank you very much :)

Comment: what does the doc of `HashMap` tell you?

Comment: "I tough[sic] the HashMap stored elements as the programmer put them in" What made you think that?

Comment: As I said, I was pretty sure I misunderstood how it worked, I was right .o.
Thank you a lot. It means, that if I would like to sort it, it would be useless? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different Map types, giving different guarantees about their key order (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)).

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): Undefined ordering of its elements.

[`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html): Order defined by insertion.

[`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html): Order defined by the `compareTo()` method of their elements.

So, HashMap makes no guarantee about it's iteration order. Once you insert another element, you will get a different ordering. From what you described a `LinkedHashMap` might be what you need.

Comment: Even if now I'm having a little problem o.o
I'm trying to use TreeMap, just to see how it works, and when I declare a variable of it, it highlights the variable name in blue(I'm using eclipse), it should highlights it in something like brown, and it is not a real variable o.o cause I can't use it, when I pass the cursor throught it, I can see the javadoc, but well I wrote a javadoc before to write it, I know I shouldn't do it for these kind of purposes, but it was just something that only I had to read, I tried putting the same code into another class, and it works :(

Comment: Nvm sorry, it was making me crazy, I just declared it out of a method lol -.-

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over your keys by *insertion* order you need to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead. The `HashMap` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) clearly states that

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which retains insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap doesn't preserve order:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. --[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

You want [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("first key", 1);
    map.put("second key", 2);
    map.put("third key", 3);

    System.out.println(map.toString());
```

output:

```
{first key=1, second key=2, third key=3}
```

If all you care about is the toString, you could also use TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap does not guarantee ordering of any kind.

From the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map

You can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you want to maintain order.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.