# How to sort HashMap entries in alphabetic order?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have made a program which will read in text from the user, and then display the letter frequencies of the user's text. I am experimenting with hashmaps and I am not sure how to display my results in alphabetical order.

I currently have:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();    
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
  Integer count = map.get(user.charAt(i)); // if not in map
  if (count == null)
    map.put(user.charAt(i), 1);
  else
    map.put(user.charAt(i), count + 1);
}
```

As my code for storing the values, but when I print the result

`System.out.println(map.entrySet());`

I get `[a=1, r=2, h=1, y=1]`. (For printing "Harry")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a collection that would implement the [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface. Try using [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which guarantees the natural ordering of its keys.

This question describes differences between various implementations of `Map`: [Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.