# How to get the previous key/value and the next key/value in Maps

Tags: java, dictionary

```
for (Entry<Double, String> entry : map.entrySet()) { 
        Double key = entry.getKey(); 
        String value = entry.getValue(); 

        // double nextKey = ?
        // String nextvalue = ?

        // double prevKey = ?
        // String prevValue = ?
    }
```

is it possible to know what the previous element and the next element while iterating the map?

Comment: Most Maps have no guaranteed ordering, so unlikely.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap

Comment: Short answer: No, not reliably. A `Set` does not have a specified order, hence.

You could save the previous/next entry in a separate variable/variables, but the order of the entries may not be the same on successive calls of this part of code.

Comment: @DaDaDom actually, there are sets that support such navigation, like `NavigableSet` implementations.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou agreed, but the return value of `.entrySet()` does not mention any such order, hence, there is no guarantee about the order.

Comment: @DaDaDom see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet--

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) for this, which `entrySet()`'s iterator return entries [in ascending key order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet--):

```
NavigableMap<Double, String> myMap = new TreeMap<>();

//...

for (Map.Entry<Double, String> e : myMap.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry<Double, String> next = myMap.higherEntry(e.getKey()); // next
    Map.Entry<Double, String> prev = myMap.lowerEntry(e.getKey());  // previous

   // do work with next and prev
}
```

Every entry retrieval is O(logN), so for full iteration this is not the most effective approach. To be more effective, on iteration just remember last 3 entries, and use 1st as prev, 2nd as current and 3rd as next, as [@Malt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30099564/3459206).

Answer (score 4):

A [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is an `OrderedMap` and a `NavigableMap` and will allow you to iterate forward and backward, allowing you to access previous and next keys with `lowerKey()` and `higherKey()` respectively. However it might not be the best solution.

Can you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, and we can give you a more fitting solution?

Comment: I need to generate key with each new addition in the map. The calculation depends on the previous and next value and the map must be sorted according to the key, which determines the position of the new addition.

Comment: Is the complexy of lowerEntry O(1) or O(log n)? After all if you already have a pointer to an element, moving in the tree can be easy.

Comment: @NathanB it's `O(log n)`. The parameter is a key not a pointer, so it works like `get()` in terms of time complexity and sort of like `get(key-1)` logically.

Comment: @Kayaman is there an implementation of TreeMap with linked list of elements to allow iterating in O(1)?

Comment: @NathanB that's a different issue. Iterating any `Map` fully is `O(n)`. You can keep track of the next/current/previous elements yourself easily with the `Iterator`, but since most maps don't have a guaranteed iteration order it doesn't make sense with all of them.