# Peek Ahead to Next Map Entry

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, treemap

My data set is a payment schedule consisting of due dates and amounts.  I'm storing this in a `TreeMap`.

```
Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> paymentSchedule = new TreeMap<>();
paymentSchedule.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01", formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
paymentSchedule.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-02-01", formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
paymentSchedule.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-03-01", formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
paymentSchedule.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-04-01", formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
paymentSchedule.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-05-01", formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
paymentSchedule.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-06-01", formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));

for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> paymentPeriod : paymentSchedule.entrySet()) {
    LocalDate dueDate = paymentPeriod.getKey();
    BigDecimal amountDue = paymentPeriod.getValue();
}
```

How can I "peek ahead" during an iteration without advancing the iteration?

For example, when I'm working with the Map.Entry for `{2017-03-01,1000}`, I want to look up the next due date for a calculation.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099237/how-to-get-the-previous-key-value-and-the-next-key-value-in-maps

Comment: Guava has a peeking Iterator.

Comment: @isaace that works

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external library you could simply create a `List` from your `entrySet` and loop over the list using the old fashioned for-with-index loop:

```
final List<Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(paymentSchedule.entrySet());
for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++) {
    Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> paymentPeriod = entryList.get(i);
    if (i < entryList.size() - 1) {
        Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> nextPaymentPeriod = entryList.get(i + 1);
    }
    LocalDate dueDate = paymentPeriod.getKey();
    BigDecimal amountDue = paymentPeriod.getValue();
}
```

Depending on the size of your map this approach will yield a better performance as the lookup of the next entry is `O(1)` and creation of the `List` is `O(n)` resulting in an overall complexity of `O(n)`. Where the `NavigableMap.higherKey()` function is `O(log(n))` resulting in a total complexity of `O(n log(n))`.