# Access and modify the next entry set while iterating a map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

While working on a problem statement, I need to access the next `Entry` of a `Map` and based on a condition, I need to modify the next entry value.

I have been considering the solution provided here: [How to get the previous key/value and the next key/value in Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099237/how-to-get-the-previous-key-value-and-the-next-key-value-in-maps) where I can access the `higherEntry` using `NavigableMap` but it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry.setValue(AbstractMap.java:797)
```

which is totally understood. Here is the code snippet

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> current : myMap.entrySet()) {

    Map.Entry<Character, Integer> next = myMap.higherEntry(current.getKey());

    if (current.getValue() == next.getValue()) {
        // Code block
    } else if (current.getValue() > next.getValue()) {
        // Code block
    } else {
        next.setValue(1); // Line that throws Exception
    }
}
```

How can I Iterate through a `Map`, access and modify the next Entry when required?

Comment: Why not just loop through the list of keys, then use the keys to retrieve the values for comparison, then use `Map.put()` to overwrite it? The implementation of the `Map` you are using uses the `SimpleImmutableEntry` implementation for the entries, which doesn't allow you to use `setValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an enhanced for loop, you can use a normal for loop and keep track of the index. This is tricky because you need a way to access the next entry and it depends on if you are using a ordered implementation of `Map` (like `LinkedHashMap`). If you are not using `LinkedHashMap` or some similar ordered map this will not be consistent and the entries could get out of order. Assuming you *are* using an ordered map, you can first convert the entry set to an array and go from there. This would look like `Map.Entry<Character, Integer>[] entries = myMap.entrySet().stream().toArray(Map.Entry[]::new);` Then, you can use a for loop along with this array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < entries.length-1; i++) {
    Map.Entry<Character, Integer> current = entries[i];
    Map.Entry<Character, Integer> next = entries[i+1];
    //code that does stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TreeMap.higherEntry` returns an *immutable* entry, and that explains the `UnsupportedOperationException` that you're seeing:

```
//exportEntry is being called by TreeMap.higherEntry(K)
static <K,V> Map.Entry<K,V> exportEntry(TreeMap.Entry<K,V> e) {
    return (e == null) ? null :
        new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e);
}
```

One possible solution/workaround is to collect your updated entries into a map and then modify your original map after the loop:

```
Map<Character, Integer> updates = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> current : myMap.entrySet()) {

    Map.Entry<Character, Integer> next = myMap.higherEntry(current.getKey());

    if(null != next) {
        if (current.getValue() == next.getValue()) {
        } else if (current.getValue() > next.getValue()) {
        } else {
            updates.put(next.getKey(), 1); // entry to be updated
        }
    }
}

myMap.putAll(updates);
```

Note that I've added a null check as `myMap.higherEntry` may return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> next = myMap.higherEntry(current.getKey());

        if(next != null)
        {
            if (current.getValue() == next.getValue())
            {
                //Code block
            }
            else if (current.getValue() > next.getValue()) {
                //Code block
            }

            else {
                myMap.put(current.getKey(), 1); 

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `higherEntry` returns an immutable entry, but you code also lacks the handling of the case that there is no higher entry. On the other hand, the next entry returned by the iterator would be the right entry anyway (if there is one), so this can be done using an `Iterator` manually, like this:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
if(it.hasNext()) {
    for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> current=it.next(), next; it.hasNext(); current=next) {
        next = it.next();
        // don't compare Integer objects via ==, use equals
        if (current.getValue().equals(next.getValue())) {
            // Code block
        } else if (current.getValue() > next.getValue()) {
            // Code block
        } else {
            next.setValue(1);
        }
    }
}
```

A “not so clean” but reasonably simple alternative would be

```
Map.Entry<Character, Integer> current = null;
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> next: myMap.entrySet()) {
    if(current != null) {
        if (current.getValue().equals(next.getValue())) {
            // Code block
        } else if (current.getValue() > next.getValue()) {
            // Code block
        } else {
            next.setValue(1);
        }
    }
    current = next;
}
```