# Android ListView with LinkedHashMap - scrambled list when scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, linkedhashmap

I've had trouble finding much documentation on using LinkedHashMap with a ListView for Android, but I was able to get the list to populate correctly with the below.

Unfortunately, when I scroll, the list is scrambled the same as it would be if I was using a regular HashMap.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**MainActivity.java** (only a portion):

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ListView dataList;
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dataList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        list=new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
        adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

        addItems();
    }

    public void addItems() {
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        row.put(KEY_COLUMN, key);
        row.put(FIRST_COLUMN, dateTime);
        row.put(SECOND_COLUMN, data1);
        row.put(THIRD_COLUMN, data2);
        row.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, data3);
        list.add(row);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter Class**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtKey;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_columns, null);
            txtKey = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_key);
            txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_time);
            txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data1);
            txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data2);
            txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data3);
        }

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        txtKey.setText(map.get(KEY_COLUMN));
        txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
        txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the list is scrambled the same as it would be if I was using a regular HashMap`?

Comment: From what I understand, HashMap (which I originally was using) scrambles the order of the rows when the data is refreshed or the list is scrolled, so LinkedHashMap was created to solve this problem (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedhashmap_class.htm).  This thread also explains the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `ArrayAdapter` rather than rolling your own `BaseAdapter` subclass. But, assuming that you really want to extend `BaseAdapter`...

First, get rid of all of the widgets from the class declaration (e.g., `TextView txtKey`), moving them to be local variables inside of `getView()`.

Then, populate those local variables whether or not you are inflating a new layout.

Other improvements:

- Never use `LayoutInflater.from()` when you have an `Activity`. Call `getLayoutInflater()` on the `Activity`, so you get a `LayoutInflater` that knows about your themes and styles.
- Use `getItem()`, instead of `list.get(position)`, in `getView()`, so `getView()` and `getItem()` stay in sync.

Comment: I was able to use your suggestion to go with ArrayAdapter vs. BaseAdapter to find these sources, which solved this issue.  Thanks!

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

https://github.com/codepath/android-custom-array-adapter-demo