# Ordering a HashMap by Key?

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, entity

I have a `HashMap` with the following entries:

**Key**- Dog Object
**Value**- Description of Dog

```
Map<Dog, List<String>> DogsAndDescriptions;
```

I would like order the HashMap by *"Oldest Dog First".*

Dog is an `Entity` that has the following field that I would like to order by:

```
 @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime birthday;
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: 1) Get your map 2) Get key set 3) Convert to list 4) Sort by age 5) Use keys from this list.

Comment: Use TreeMap if you want the keys ordered.

Comment: @Eran Probably he is getting it from DB. Not sure.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can you please give an example of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really possible as HashMaps are specially an unordered list.

You could use java.util.LinkedHashMap which uses insertion order but what I think you really want here is [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which will support natrual ordering of the elements within it.

If you add a Comparator which spits out the oldest dog then the TreeMap sort them in that order for you.

A TreeMap is an implementation of the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface so you interact with it in the same way as you do just now.

```
TreeMap<Dog, List<String>> dogsAndDescriptions = new TreeMap<Dog, List<String>>();
```

Would instantiate an instance of your (don't capitalise your variables) dogsAndDescriptions Map. What you can do as part of the TreeMap constructor is pass in a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which will govern how your dogs get sorted as keys, or make Dog class extend Comparable and override the compareTo method basically something like

```
class Dog implements Comparable<Dog>{
    //somecode

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dog o) {
        return birthday.compareTo(o.birthday);
    }
}
```

So you can see that will compare dogs based on their birthday. I'll link to an [example here](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treemap/comparator-user-object/) as how Comparators work is a different question I think. But that's 2 ways to sort them.

Comment: Ok can you please give an example of this? I am not familiar with the treemap data structure

Comment: I've added some more detail to my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure If I was clear enough, I am looking to order the KEYS in the map rather than the values inside them. For example: The key A should come before Key B if Key A contains an older dog than Key B, is this possible?

Comment: OK thanks, so When I initialise the treemap they will already be ordered?

Comment: I have implemented your solution but when I run I get the error:" Kennel cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable" ? I have implemented the comparable interface in the Dog class, do I need it in Kennel also?

Comment: I got it fixed thanks so much! Can you look at a similar question I am now having here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742915/ordering-the-keys-in-a-treemap-dependant-on-the-oldest-value-in-its-list-of-valu

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll have a look at your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `Comparable<Dog>` interface in your `Dog` class with implementation which would compere `Dog`'s `birthday` and use `TreeMap<Dog, List<String>>` to store `Dog` objects in it. Below is sample implementation for `Dog` class:

```
    class Dog implements Comparable<Dog>{
        public Dog(String name, Date dob) {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthday = dob;
        }

        private String name;
        private Date birthday;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Dog o) {
            return birthday.compareTo(o.birthday);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

*Note:* I have note used any additional annotation for simplicity.

You can not use `HashMap` for preserving some sort order on `Dog` key as `HashCode` does not preserve any order. For more info, please refer : [Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)