# Ordering the Keys in a TreeMap dependant on the oldest value in its list of values?

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have a `TreeMap` as follows:

```
  TreeMap<Parent, List<Child>> mapOfParentsAndChilds = new TreeMap<Parent, List<Child>>();
```

I want to *order* the Map by the following condition:

The First key (Parent object) in the Map will be the one that has the *oldest child* in their list of values.

i.e. If the oldest child in Parent A's list of values was **20** years old, and the oldest child in Parent B's list of values was **19** years old then Parent A should be **before** Parent B in the map and so on.

How can I implement this solution?

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child
{
    //other vars 

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

}
```

Comment: If two parents have oldest children of the same age, only one will be kept in the map because they will be deemed equal. Is that what you want? Why do you want/need to use a TreeMap? There may be a simpler/better option.

Comment: Ok I did not know that was the case, I don't need to use a treemap I just know it allows comparators so I tried it. What else can you suggest?

Comment: If you have a list of parents and want it sorted, you can also call  `Collections.sort(parents, comparator);`. This will keep "duplicates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a map with custom sorting you can use the constructor which takes a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). A comparator lets you decide how to order keys.

In Java 8 [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) was added, which makes creating a comparator using the new [streaming](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/lambdas-and-streams-in-java-8-libraries/240166818) feature easy. If you're not familiar with Java 8 streams, read up on them. They're incredibly powerful and convenient.

```
Map<Parent, List<Children>> mapOfParentsAndChildren = new TreeMap<>(
    Comparator.comparing(parent ->
        parent.getChildren().stream()
            .mapToInt(Child::getAge)
            .min().orElse(0)
    )
    .thenComparing(System::identityHashCode)
);
```

Notice that the list of children needs to be accessible from the parent object. You can't order a map's keys by a property of the keys' corresponding values because map values can change.

> @assylias: If two parents have oldest children of the same age, only one will be kept in the map because they will be deemed equal.

To fix that, we can chain an additional comparator using [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-). This extra comparator is used if the first one says the oldest children are equal. You can add in whatever additional criteria you want to decide which parent wins in that case. I threw in `System::identityHashCode` as a tie breaker. `identityHashCode` returns an arbitrary, yet consistent integer. In essence I'm using it to ensure different parents compare unequal, but which one goes first is arbitrary.

If you have some better criterion to use, I encourage you to change this. For instance, if each parent has a unique name, `.thenComparing(Parent::getName)` would be better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try this, how does this work? I am very new to comparators?

Comment: Ok thanks, in a comment above my original question it stated that: "If two parents have oldest children of the same age, only one will be kept in the map because they will be deemed equal". Is this correct? I ask as I want to keep all children within the map.

Comment: This will work though perhaps not the easiest to understand code. Using the new Java 8 features though so that's good, I've not really touched on this as I was about to write a much more verbose old school answer. This is a good answer.

Comment: ok, do I need to implement the comparable interface on my Child entity?

Comment: Also, should "parent" in your solution be the Parent Class or an actual parent object (lower case) ?

Comment: @AndrewAitken I am also interested in seeing your solution

Comment: You do not need `Child` to implement `Comparable`. You could have `Parent` implement `Comparable` if you want to move the logic out of the tree map. `parent` in my answer is a `Parent` object. The lowercase is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I do not understand how it is a Parent object? Do I need to declare these Objects above the treemap in my code? I ask as I am used to instantiating Maps with the upper class class as opposed to objects. E.g.:  Map<Parent, List<Child>> mapOfParentsAndChildren = new HashMap<Parent, List<Child>>();