# Difference between LinkedHashmap and LinkedTreemap

Tags: java, rest-assured

as `java.util.LinkedHashmap` exist and what is the advantage to use `import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;`

When i searched, i got the results comparison between `HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMAp` but i want to know the performance of `LinkedTreeMap` different from either `LinkedHashMap or TreeMap`.

Please any one clarify me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap

Comment: Since `LinkedTreeMap` is apparently internal to gson, why do you need to know?

Comment: Hi Andy, in our automation scripts my seniors used `LinkedTreeMap` where ever need, at the same place even `LinkedHashMap` is working, i want to know which is better to use.

Comment: It is always better to use classes from a public API as chances are better that it does not change unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the performance part:

`Hashmap` and `LinkedHashMap` supports O(1) get/put operations complexity time. `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order of the inserted items.

`TreeMap` supports O(log n) get/put operations complexity time. Since it has a mechanism to preserver natural order of the items using `Comparable` or `Comparator`.

Comment: but what can be the performance of `LinkedTreeMap`, can you please tell about this. As for as i know even LinkedTreeMap also preserves the order of the insertion.

Comment: From the implementation, it is so similar to the `TreeMap`, it uses `Comparable` and `Comparator` as well. I guess they have the same performance complexity. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have less reputation to upvote your answer, once i get the required reputation, definitely i will upvote your answer.