# MultiLine Listview sorted randomly

Tags: java, android

So I have this code for a ListView with 2 lines in Android Studio.

```
 ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AboutListView);

    HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new HashMap<>();
    nameAddresses.put("Diana", "3214 Broadway Avenue");
    nameAddresses.put("Tyga", "343 Rack City Drive");
    nameAddresses.put("Rich Homie Quan", "111 Everything Gold Way");
    nameAddresses.put("Donna", "789 Escort St");
    nameAddresses.put("Bartholomew", "332 Dunkin St");
    nameAddresses.put("Eden", "421 Angelic Blvd");

    List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.line1, R.id.line2});


    Iterator it = nameAddresses.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
        resultsMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
        listItems.add(resultsMap);
    }

    resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView android:id="@+id/line2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

And for some reason, the items are not showing up how I want. They're showing in random order not in the order they're formatted in the code.
[app preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYv3V.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do away with nameAddresses and the iterator. Build up your list items directly.

Comment: I am very beginner in Java the code I currently have is from a tutorial. Can you replace that part for me?

Comment: I think is your `HashMap` cause this you can use `LinkedHashMap`. `HashMap` has no order.

Comment: Check at this post for what i said. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating a `HashMap` is not guaranteed to access elements in the same order you added them in. If you need that property, use a `LinkedHashMap` or an `ArrayList`. The former will be easier for you to convert your existing code to, simply replace

```
HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new HashMap<>();
```

with

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```