# Java, setting a string array equal to a double array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with part of this java project. So part of this project is setting notes equal to a frequency. I made a string array of notes and a double array of frequencies but i don't know how to set the string array equal to the double so that when a note is played, it plays to the specific frequency of the double array. If there is a better method of doing this?

```
double[] freq = {
  16.35, 17.32, 17.32, 18.35, 19.45, 19.45, 20.60, 21.83, 23.12,
  23.12, 24.50, 25.96, 25.96, 27.50, 29.14, 29.14, 30.87
};
String[] notes = {
  "C0", "C#0", "Db0", "D0", "D#0", "Eb0", "E0", "F0", "F#0",
  "Gb0", "G0", "G#0", "Ab0", "A0", "A#0", "Bb0", "B0"
};
```

here are the two arrays.

Comment: You should probably use a `map` instead

Comment: simple: by the index(if done correctly).

Comment: Definitely read up on how to use a `Map` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html - and try out a `HashMap<String, Double>`.

Comment: @gfos suggestion is the best option for you.

Comment: a map is not necessaryly the best idea as it doesn't keep an order which may be important.... especially if you go for sound: e.g. an oktave doubles the frequency.

Comment: @kai - It depends on the implementation of `Map`.  A `TreeMap` holds keys in order according to natural key order (`Comparable`) or a key order defined by a `Comparator`.  A `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion ordering.

Comment: you  need a fn like:  0->C 1->C# ... or you calculate the freq. map is good if you want to index the other way round C->0 ...

Comment: He appears to be mapping from String to double.  But the question is very unclear.  (Joshua ... you should do something about that!  The ability to communicate ideas clearly is a job requirement for most IT jobs ....)

Comment: @kai How could the order possibly matter if all he is doing is lookups?

Comment: see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(music)#Note_names

Answer (score 0):

You should create one **Java Map** object with

> key:value

pairs instead of two different Arrays.
Here is Java documentation of Map class and it's types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Here are some examples of implementation:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/

But first check what type of Map do you need. Here is well explained difference:
[Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)

**Example**:

```
HashMap<String, Double> notesMap = new HashMap<>();
notesMap.put("C0", 16.35); ...
```

Add all notes and then you can get frequencies by note name, and iterate through all properties of a **HashMap**.

If it's one-to-many **relationship**, you should solve this with creating the Note class with name and frequency variables.

Answer (score 0):

In case the order of the arrays matters, or if your assignment is limited to arrays, this is the solution I would use (although definitely not as efficient as a Map)

```
noteToTest = scanner.nextLine();

for(x = 0; x < notes.length; x++)
{
     if(noteToTest.equalsIgnoreCase(notes[x])
     {

          System.out.println("The frequency is :" + freq[x]);

     }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a map, the "more type safe" answer: create a Note class, like:

```
 public class Note {
   private final String name;
   private final double frequency;

   public Note(String name, double frequency) {
     this.name = name; ...
```

You could then go on and put the **play** method into class, too.

The next other options would be to use an **enum** instead of a class, as obviously, the note `Note("C0", 16.35)` doesn't need to be created more than once ...

Please note: in any case, you want your data to somehow represent that **relationship** between a name and the corresponding frequency. Your current code is creating that mapping implicitly, based on the **same** index in two different arrays. And as shown, you can now decide how you can make things more explicit.