# Store each character occurence

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I want to design a data structure to store occurence if each character in java.
for eg: for the given below string

```
DDDTTNNDD
```

my data structure should look something like this

```
D-[[0,2],[7,8]]
T-[[3,4]]
N-[[5,6]]
```

I have something like this in mind but dont know exactly what datastructure in java to use

```
Map<String,Set<>>
```

using set because dont want the occurence to repeat

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Only thing I would change is to create a separate class for an occurrence so you have control over `equals()` which `Set` uses to determine equality so you can define what a *duplicate* actually is.

As you are defining a range with a `start` and `end` *duplicate* could theoretically mean multiple things.

- Start and end must match exactly for it to be a duplicate (this is implemented below but probably not what you want here): `[0, 2]` and `[1, 2]` would **not** be considered a *duplicate* here.
- Two ranges in a `Set` must not have an intersection (this is likely what you want): `[0, 2]` and `[1, 2]` would be considered a *duplicate* here.
- ...

Take for instance this class:

```java
public class Occurrence{
        private int start;
        private int end;

        public Occurrence(int start, int end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Occurrence that = (Occurrence) o;
            return start == that.start && end == that.end;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(start, end);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" +
                    + start +
                    ", " + end +
                    ']';
        }
    }
```

Then you could use the data structure like this:

```java
var ds = new HashMap<String, Set<Occurrence>>();
```

Only other thing you could then think about is which map to use. I suggest you take [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap) as a point of reference to make up your mind and make a conscious choice in the end.