# Should I use LinkedHashMap or TreeMap if I insert and access in order?

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap, linkedhashmap, ordereddictionary

If i put and iterate in natural order, should I use `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap`?

I will use a `Map<int, MyObj>`, and I will put them in natural order (1,2,3,...).
I know about their big-O time performances, but I also know that this is a borderline use.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17708526/17487348) should tell you everything you need to know. The question is which order you want to preserve. Natural order or insertion order?

Comment: If you insert and access in order, why aren't you using a List?

Comment: What are your criteria for selection?

Comment: @Mushroomator I wrote that natural order and insertion order will be the same, also I already have seen that answer, but it did not help me.

Comment: @thatotherguy I will consider that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TreeMap`. Not for any performance reasons, but because it can be assigned to `SortedMap` (or `NavigableMap`), and that communicates clearly your intent that the map has a defined order.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to keep the entries in the order in which you originally insert them, use `LinkedHashMap`.
- If you want the entries kept in a sorted order, use a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), the successor to `SortedMap`. Java comes with two such implementations: [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).  The latter is thread-safe.

The sorted maps by default use [natural order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). Optionally, you can provide a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to use for sorting. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.