# Iterating LinkedHashMap values from the key

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I'm struggling with a little bit of code, and I just cannot figure out what the correct syntax would be. Here is an example of the problem:

```
for (Integer key : map1.keySet()) {

    for (Integer value : map2.values()) {

        if (value == key) {

            // ++ the corresponding value of the looping map1 key.
            // tried statements like map1.values()++  
            // but this is an invalid operation.

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to loop `map1` keys through `map2` values and if within this process a `map1` key matches a `map2` value, I want to add one to the value of the corresponding `map1` key.

Should be a simple problem but Eclipse keeps telling me that I have the syntax wrong, can anyone suggest what statement I may need to iterate the values?

Comment: please add Eclipse syntax error

Comment: A stacktrace would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with a very small modification to your code:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    for (Integer value : map2.values()) {
        if (value.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            entry.setValue(entry.getValue()+1);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Since `map2` could contain the same *value* more than once, the other solution that uses a hash set to speed things up will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help! with this set up I am getting just 1 for the values of map1. I need plus 1 for each time a map1 key equals a map2 value. Do I just need to move the "+1" elsewhere?

Comment: @user2941526 I see - `map2` can have the same value multiple times, right? Then you should the version with two loops.

Comment: You should probably use `.equals`, not `==`, since you're working with boxed `Integer` objects.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Absolutely! Thank you very much - I copy/pasted the code, and missed this important issue. Great spotting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Eclipse report a syntax error, but in any case this loop does not make much sense, consider changing it to:

```
for (Integer value : map2.values())
    if (map1.containsKey(value))
        // bla bla
```

it will run in O(n) rather than the former O(n*m)

when n is the size of map2 and m is the size of map1 (as notified by @dasblinkenlight)

Comment: I believe a map should find in and average of O(1)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1

Comment: yes, as you can see I look for the key there, thats why I switched the order of the blocks

Comment: Gee, you're right, I did not notice that you've switched the order of the loops. You should mention that `n` is the size of `map2`, because the sizes of the two maps may differ.

Answer (score 0):

How you init yours maps? Like `Map<Integer, Integer> map1=new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();` or `Map map1=new LinkedHashMap();` If the second way the key will be Object not Integer. And in all cases compare two Integer using == bad practise. Use equals

Answer (score 0):

You can use [containsKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method like this:

```
for (Integer value : map2.values()){
if (map1.containsKey(value))
    map1.put(key, value);

...
}
```