# Complexity of java hashmap for hash of string

Tags: java, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was looking at java source code in HashMap class.

```
final int hash(Object k) {
    int h = 0;
    if (useAltHashing) {
        if (k instanceof String) {
            return sun.misc.Hashing.stringHash32((String) k);
        }
        h = hashSeed;
    }

    h ^= k.hashCode();
```

So, what is the time complexity of hashmapObject.put("somestring") ?
Is it O(1) or O(n) where n is number of characters in a string.

Comment: Adding something to a `HashMap` is guaranteed to be `O(1)` (assuming perfect hash distribution). _Your_ hash function might be `O(whatever)` though... And your `equals`...

Comment: Check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1) out

Answer (score 2):

In worst case time(In practise it happens rarely , only when we have a bad hashing function) complexity for `put` method in hashmap is `O(N)`, because although we add the element at the beginning of the linked list(`O(1)`) but we still need to loop through the bucket(linked list) to determine if that new element already exists or not.

**Updated:**
As per [Peter Lawery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) comment in java 8 its `O(log n)`. This optimization is described [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180) but in a nutshell
 an ad-hoc implementation of tree map is used as a bucket when the size of the bucket  crosses the threshold value. The threshold value is setted by the variable `static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8;` in `HashMap.java`

Comment: Hash map (or hash table) is an associative array.  It *can* be implemented with a linked list, but I don't believe the Java one is. I didn't down vote by the way.

Comment: That being said, your answer isn't wrong.  Just can be more accurate. You are correct in saying the `put` function has a worse case scenario of `O(n)`

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc The bucket in java is linkedList(not java.util.LinkedList but simpler version). There is also a variable table which is indeed an array that contains object of type linkedList

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Java `HashMap` uses a version of a linked list for allowing multiple items in the same bucket.

Comment: @Vulcan But in order for hash map implementation to achieve it goal it need to relay on some data structure for bucket. OP ask for time-complexity

Comment: Worst case complexity only happens if the hash function is degenerate - worth mentioning that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i thought it is self-evident but thanks for suggesting i updated my answer. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Note: in Java 8 it degenerates into a tree with O(log N) instead of O(N).

Comment: @PeterLawrey didn't realise they'd changed the impl of `HashMap` in Java 8 - got a reference? Worth a read...

Comment: @BoristheSpider not that I know of, just had a look at the code. Actually if you look at ConcurrentHashMap, it is ~ 3x longer in Java 8 than Java 7. :P

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think this optimization is described  http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180 as well

Comment: @BoristheSpider for more details http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-performance

Answer (score 2):

It is *O(1)* w.r.t. the size of the map, which is what is usually of interest. It is *O(N)* w.r.t. the length of the string.