# Embedded Hash Map Big(O)?

Tags: java, hashmap, big-o

If you embed a hash map like so:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>();
Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

innerMap.put("x","y");
map.put("z", innerMap);

innerMap = map.get("z"); <---------- O(1) time
String y = innerMap.get("x"); <-------- O(1) time
```

Does this mean that as long as both maps search times stay relatively close to O(1) then you can essentially search through a second level of a hashmap still in O(1) time?

My internship responsibilities have me dealing heavily with data comparisons and I used something similar to this the other day. I had a string key value that was the name of a certain "Plan" and a value as a hashmap. The internal hashmap had a string key value of an employee ID and a relationship(if an employee was visited twice meaning they had two different coverage levels within the plan from the external map, then their relationship would be updated. Was my choice of DS here a good one? I was attempting to achieve a lookup & edit time of O(1)

Comment: Yes, this is still `O(1)`, since the time it takes to access an element is not affected by how many elements exist.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more introduction.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1) has more details about HashMaps specifically.  In general, yes, if you have two O(1) operations, the result should be O(1).  However, the constants hidden in the big-O will get larger.

Comment: the search of hashmap is constant time. 2 * C = 2C = O(1) anyway

Answer (score 4):

`O(1)` doesn't mean "completes in one step". It means it completes in (approximately) the same amount of time no matter how large the population. That's why `O(1)` is also called *constant time*.

A fixed number of repetitions of a constant time operation is also constant time, ie `O(1)`.

The answer is "yes", your data structure has `O(1)` time complexity for accessing values from the nested maps.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking if the runtime of finding an element in a hashmap within another hashmap is constant. The answer is **yes**. Because think about a hashmap of hashmaps first. As you said earlier, the time it takes to find a value using a key is constant. The total runtime is just this twice; therefore O(1) * 2 = O(2) which is still O(1). Of course, you have to consider collisions, which in excess, can slow down the searching process. This can be avoided of course by picking a suitable load factor.