# Which Algorithm does firebase is using behind datasnapshot.haschild()?

Tags: android, algorithm, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Explanation -

```
DatabaseReference Ref;
//intialize Ref variable
Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();  //root reference
```

after this, adding the valueEventListener to Ref

```
Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("abcd")) {
                //abcd child is present
            }else {
                //abcd child is not present
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now Specifically my question is which algorithm does the firebase using behind the `dataSnapshot.hasChild("abcd")` ?

In Firebase-database if my root reference contains a huge number of childs then this is an efficient method to use or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataSnapshot` is an efficiently-generated immutable copy of the data at a Firebase Database location. It can't be modified and will never change.

The `hasChild(key)` can be considered a convenience method for `child(key).exists()`. As keys are always unique, there is no need to iterate the entire snapshot to locate a specific key, and therefore performance should be something similar to a [HashMap at `O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1).

If you do have a huge amount of data though, it is often unnecessary to download everything at once, so it's recommended to [filter or restrict](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) your query, or select a deeper node and then only obtain a subset of data at a time.

For example, you could listen lower in the tree, for the `abcd` node directly, and then use the `exists()` method instead to check for the existence of a child node:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.child("abcd").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot child = dataSnapshot.child("efgh");
            if (child.exists()) {
                //efgh child is present
            } else {
                //efgh child is not present
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {  }
    });
```

Comment: Great answer @Grimthorr! You're correct that `hasChild()` can be expressed as a `exists()` (see for example the JavaScript implementation of [`hasChild()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/src/api/DataSnapshot.ts#L113) and [`exists()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/src/api/DataSnapshot.ts#L78)). The latter is preferred, since it retrieves less data. Btw: it would be great if you could expand your answer with an example of OPs code, but then using `exists()` and listening lower in the tree.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks very much Frank, glad my assumption was correct. I've updated the answer to remove the uncertainty, added an example and clarified it a little.