# Why is the complexity of the hash function not considered in the complexity of HashMap's operations?

Tags: java, hashmap

For a `HashMap<String, String> map` each time a key-value pair is inserted into the map a hash is calculated -

```
java.lang.String#hashCode

public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

As it's pretty self-explanatory, the complexity of put operation is basically the complexity of the hash calculation.

So what should be the appropriate way to define hashmap worst-case time complexity for put/get operation?

If you have the same question from hash collision perspective, here you can find the answer:
[Is a Java hashmap really O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1)

Comment: That code won't compile (where does `hash` come from?). Also, what *exactly* is your programming question / the problem you're having?

Comment: @Todd this is not a duplicate - That question is referring to something different.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt That code is ripped from String source - `hash` is the cached hash value for String. True store, some strings (like "polygenelubricants", will hash to 0 causing them to be computed every time `hashCode()` is called!!

Comment: @ravi This is not the same question. Please have a look again

Comment: Hash function's complexity is not considered because `HashMap.put` complexity refers to the complexity regarding the number of buckets in the map, i.e. its capacity. In this sense, it's `O(1)`. Of course that if the hash function takes too long to execute, it will have a negative impact on the overall performance of the whole datastructure.

Comment: But I think there are actually answers to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you calculate time complexity as a function of `N`, you must first decide what `N` represents. When we talk about the complexity of `HashMap` operations, `N` represents the size of the `HashMap` (i.e. the number of key-value pairs stored in the `HashMap`).

The time complexity of `hashCode()` of a given key does not depend on the number of entries in the `HashMap`. Therefore it takes `O(1)` time to compute the `hashCode()` (assuming the length of the `String` key in your example is not a function of the size of the `Map` - we can construct a strange `HashMap<String,String>` where the `i`th key put in the `Map` has `i` characters - in that edge case, `hashCode()` calculation would take `O(N)` time, and as a result, all the `HashMap` operations will require `O(N)` time instead of `O(1)`).

Once you compute the `hashCode()`, it takes `O(1)` time to find out whether the key is already present in the `Map` (since the average number of entries in each bucket of the `HashMap` is bound by a constant).

Comment: Can you clarify *"since the average number of entries in each bucket of the HashMap is bound by a constant"* please ?

Comment: @bonnal-enzo `HashMap` has a load factor, which is usually < 1 (the default value is 0.75). For load factor 0.75, if a `HashMap` has 1000 buckets, it will have at most 750 entries (the number of buckets will be increased when you try to add the 751st entry). Therefore the average number of entries in each bucket <= 750/1000, which is a constant (and a small one).

Comment: Very clear thanks, do you know by which factor is typically multiplied the number of buckets when the threshold is reached ? by 2 ?

Comment: @bonnal-enzo yes. The number of buckets is a power of 2, and is multiplied by 2 when the HashMap is resized.

Answer (score 5):

Big O notation is talking about the complexity of the operation. Most operations become more complex (i.e. take more time) when there are more elements involved and the notation describes how that complexity grows relative to the number of elements.

With O(1), you are saying that the operation is independent of the number of elements involved. The hash operation may be fast or slow for its own reasons, but that speed will not vary whether you have a HashMap of 1 element or a googolplex of them.

It should be noted that O(1) is the amortized average and not guaranteed. The worst case is considered to be O(n), assumed to be a hash function that returns the same hash each time, but it's conceivable (as proposed by user889742 in the comments) to have a deliberately bad hashcode function that performs even worse than that.

Comment: It is entirely possible that the size of each element is related to the total number of elements. ( For example, serial numbers, needing more digits as the number of elements grow. ) In this case, this hash function would get slower as the number of elements grow.

Comment: You're absolutely right that some hashcode implementations can cause a HashMap not to behave with O(1) complexity on insertion, O(1) is the average that presumes a good hashcode implementation. Worst-case is usually considered O(n) where all hashes are the same. I'm not sure if deliberately bad hashcodes have been considered; one that performs an infinite loop has pretty poor performance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to know what the `(1)` is for. It's for the number of elements in the array. The cost to insert into a HashMap doesn't change depending on how many elements are in the map (assuming you've amortized the cost of the insert over the entire lifetime of the structure.)

Your correct that computing the hashCode of a `String` is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the String. But once you have it you have it for ever no matter how many times you use it. So it's cost is considered constant.