# Why are these loop & hashing operations take O(N) time complexity?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, big-o

Given the array :

```
int arr[]= {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3}
```

You are asked to find a number within the array that occurs *odd* number of times. It's 3 (occurring 3 times). The time complexity should be at least O(n).
The solution is to use an *`HashMap`*. Elements become *keys* and their *counts* become values of the hashmap.

```
// Code belongs to geeksforgeeks.org
// function to find the element occurring odd 
    // number of times 

    static int getOddOccurrence(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>(); 
        // Putting all elements into the HashMap 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            if(hmap.containsKey(arr[i])) 
            { 
                int val = hmap.get(arr[i]); 
                // If array element is already present then 
                // increase the count of that element. 
                hmap.put(arr[i], val + 1);  
            } 
            else
                // if array element is not present then put 
                // element into the HashMap and initialize  
                // the count to one. 
                hmap.put(arr[i], 1);  
        } 

        // Checking for odd occurrence of each element present 
          // in the HashMap  
        for(Integer a:hmap.keySet()) 
        { 
            if(hmap.get(a) % 2 != 0) 
                return a; 
        } 
        return -1; 
    }
```

I don't get why this overall operation takes *O(N)* time complexity. If I think about it, the loop alone takes *O(N)* time complexity. Those `hmap.put` (an insert operation) and `hmap.get`(a find operations) take *O(N)* and they are nested within the loop. So normally I would think this function takes *O(N^2)* times. Why it instead takes *O(N)*?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't get why this overall operation takes O(N) time complexity.

You must examine all elements of the array - `O(N)`

For each element of the array you call `contain`, `get` and `put` on the array.  These are `O(1)` operations.  Or more precisely, they are `O(1)` on averaged *amortized over the lifefime of the `HashMap`*.  This is due to the fact that a `HashMap` will grow its hash array when the ratio of the array size to the number of elements exceeds the load factor.

O(N) repetitions of 2 or 3 O(1) operations is O(N).  QED

Reference:

- [Is a Java hashmap really O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1)

---

Strictly speaking there are a couple of scenarios where a `HashMap` is not `O(1)`.

- If the hash function is poor (or the key distribution is pathological) the hash chains will be unbalanced.  With early `HashMap` implementations, this could lead to (worst case) `O(N)` operations because operations like `get` had to search a long hash chain.  With recent implementations, `HashMap` will construct a balanced binary tree for any hash chain that is too long.  That leads to worst case `O(logN)` operations.
- `HashMap` is unable to grow the hash array beyond 2^31 hash buckets.  So at that point `HashMap` complexity starts transitioning to `O(log N)` complexity.  However if you have a map that size, other secondary effects will probably have affected the real performance anyway.

Comment: So technically it doesn't matter if there are some collisions occur (internally) during the hashing operation. We exclude those considerations over  particular DS implementation?

Comment: Nah ok i understand. Beside those operations (within the loop) don't depend on *N* anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Correct.  The complexity analysis is based on the average length of a hash chain.  The HashMap strategy of growing the array should keep the *average* length small; i.e. less than 2.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm first iterates the array of numbers, of size `n`, to generate the map with counts of occurrences.  It should be clear why this is an `O(n)` operation.  Then, after the hashmap has been built, it iterates that map and finds all entries whose counts are odd numbers.  The size of this map would in practice be somewhere between 1 (in the case of all input numbers being the same), and `n` (in the case where all inputs are different).  So, this second operation is also bounded by `O(n)`, leaving the entire algorithm `O(n)`.